# End a Windows 10 background user session without switching to it?

Tags: windows, user-accounts, session, logout

Let's say I'm an admin on my Windows home machine, logged in to my account, and another account is also logged in, in the background.

Is there a way for me to terminate that background session/account without having to log into it first? I'm asking the equivalent of this Mac question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3492/log-out-other-user-w-o-first-switching-to-that-user

Comment: If you're an admin I'm pretty sure you can do this from Task Manager. Are you asking for a programmatic way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done from **Task Manager** or from **cmd**

Method #1

1. Open **Task Manger**
2. Click on the **Users** tab
3. Find the user session you want to log off and right-click it
4. Select **Sign off**

[image: logoff through task manager]

Method #2

1. Open cmd prompt as administrator
2. enter `query session`
3. Make note of the session ID number that corresponds to the account you want to logoff
4. enter `logoff <ID #>`

[image: logoff through command]